# Scheduling a push notification in android

Tags: php, cron, scheduled-tasks, google-cloud-messaging

I have a php file with the script to send notifications to various registered android devices. Right now I use crontab to schedule the execution of the php file on the server. Is there any other standard way of sending push notifications to devices PERIODICALLY?

Answer (score 2):

Cron is a good option. It really depends on the situation when you want to send push message and to how many devices ? You can even use worker processes instead of cron.